# passportJS serializeUser and deserializeUser never called

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to figure out what I've done wrong here. After looking at the documentation (which is sadly outdated) and searching the web I believe I have everything for passport configured correctly but for some reason neither serializeUser nor deserializeUser are being called which results in req.user never being set.

Okay so here is my root server.js file (summarized)

```
/**
 * Module dependencies
 */

var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
    http = require('http'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    path = require('path'),
    routes = require('./server/routes/index'),
    secret = process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    session = require('express-session'),
    FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

/**
 * Configuration
 */

// all environments
app.set('http-port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public');
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cookieParser(secret));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// development enviornment only
if (env === 'development') {
  app.use(session({ 
    cookie: { maxAge: (60 * 60 * 10) }, // User session will expire after 60     minutes.
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: secret,
  }));
  app.use(errorHandler());
}

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

/**
 * Routes
 */

routes.SESSION_SECRET = secret; // Set env var for the router;
app.use('/', routes); // Handle defined routes
app.get('/', routes.index); // Serve index
app.get('*', routes.index); // Redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)

/**
 * Start Server
 */

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(app.get('http-port'), function () {
  console.log('Express http server listening on port ' + app.get('http-port'));
});
```

You'll notice this line above:

```
routes = require('./server/routes/index'),
```

Here is that routes file (summarized):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var auth = require('./modules/auth');

// AUTH ROUTES
router.post('/login', auth.login); // Log a local user into the application     using passport
router.post('/ldap-login', auth.ldapLogin); // Log a LDAP user into the     application using passport
router.get('/logout', auth.logout); // Log the current user out of the system
router.get('/isLoggedIn', auth.isLoggedIn); // Check is the user is logged in
router.post('/updatePassword', auth.updatePassword); // Updates a users password
```

Again you'll notice this reference:

```
var auth = require('./modules/auth');
```

Here's the auth module (summarized).

```
'use strict'
var passport = require('passport');
var secret = process.env.SESSION_SECRET;
var crypto = require('../../crypto');
var models = require('../../models');
var User = models.User;

require('../../passport');

// Log a local user into the application using passport
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if(err) { return next(err); }

    if(user) {
      User.find({
        where: {
          email: user.email
        }
      })
      .then(function(currentUser) {
        if(currentUser) {
          currentUser.updateAttributes({
            last_login: new Date()
          });
        }
      });
      user.email = crypto.decrypt(user.email);
      user.first_name = crypto.decrypt(user.first_name);
      user.last_name = crypto.decrypt(user.last_name);
      return res.json({ token: user.generateJWT(secret) });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);  
}
```

In that file I make a reference to my passport configuration which contains the functions I expect to hit.

```
require('../../passport');
```

Here's the passport config being referenced there (summarized).

```
(function() {
  var models = require('./models');
  var User = models.User;

  /**
   * Passport authentication
   */
  var passport = require('passport');

  // Passport Local Strategy
  var locStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

  passport.use(new locStrategy({
      usernameField: 'username'
    },
    function(username, password, done) {
      User.find({
        where: {
          username: username
        }
      })
      .then(function(user) {
        if(!user) {
          console.log('No such user found');
          return done(null, false);
        }
        user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
          if(err) {
            console.log('Error checking password. Error: ' + err);
            return done(err);
          } else if(!isMatch) {
            // Password did not match
            console.log('Passwords did not match');
            return done(null, false);
          } else {
            // Success
            console.log('User logged in');
            return done(null, user);
          }
        });      
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Error logging user in. Message: ' + err);
        return done(err);
      });
    }
  ));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializeUser'); // I expect this to be logged
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('deserializeUser'); // I expect this to be logged
    done(null, user);
  });

  exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate(['local', 'ldapauth']);
})();
```

You'll have noticed a reference to the User model there but since that works fine I won't include any of the code.

I'm not sure what is wrong here that is preventing me from hitting the passport.serializeUser and passport.deserializeUser methods above. I thought I might have needed to include those methods in the server.js root so I tried moving the methods both above the session({}) config and after the passport.session() call and neither change had any effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, hopefully I can help someone else.

To call deserializeUser you need to manually call req.login() once passport.authenticate() resolves. I hadn't done that because in the Passport documentation it says:

```
"Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically."
```

Which at least to me sounds like passport should call login and in turn deserializeUser automaticaly when you call passport.authenticate(), but that is incorrect.

Here is the updated code in my auth module from above:

```
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if(err) { return next(err); }

    if(user) {
      User.find({
        where: {
          email: user.email
        }
      })
      .then(function(currentUser) {
        if(currentUser) {
          currentUser.updateAttributes({
            last_login: new Date()
          })
        }
      });
      user.email = crypto.decrypt(user.email);
      user.first_name = crypto.decrypt(user.first_name);
      user.last_name = crypto.decrypt(user.last_name);
      req.login(user, function(err) { // I added req.login() here and now deserializeUser is being called and req.user is being set correctly.
        if(err) {
          return res.status(401).json(err);
        } else {
          return res.json({ token: user.generateJWT(secret) });
        }
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json(info);
    }
  })(req, res, next);  
}
```